# When configuring the number of core threads in the thread pool, should we use the number of physical cores or logical cores of the CPU?

Tags: java, docker, cpu, threadpool, vmware

When the java program sets thread pool parameters, it will refer to the number of cpu cores.
When configuring the number of core threads in the thread pool, should we use the number of physical cores or logical cores of the CPU?
In addition, I also want to know the number of CPU cores displayed by container technology, such as docker or vmware, is the number of logical cores or the number of physical cores?
For CPUs that support hyper-threading, these two values are different.

Comment: Be aware that a CPU with hyper-threading can have that feature disabled if the sysadmin so chooses.

Comment: There is not a single answer to this, as it will actually depend on what your threads will be doing (e.g. CPU-bound work vs IO-bound work). In addition, just looking at it in the form of logical/hyper-threading or physical cores is too simple, especially when working with virtualization technology like Kubernetes.

Comment: Also, Java can report on the number of CPUs it *thinks* it has available, either because the OS reported that to Java (possibly taking into account quotas or virtualization limits), or it was configured with a specific value on the commandline.

Comment: You may intentionally want to set the thread pool larger than the number of cores (physical, virtual, CPU execution units).  If one of them is blocked on something like database I/O, that would let another thread work rather than forcing a CPU to sit idle.  This is more of a tuning question, along the same lines as "what should I set the heap size to".